# Is it normal in javascript to have to consistently check returns for undefined/null values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, null, undefined

In the company I work on, in pretty much every promise return, be from a query in database to Http requests, there is a consistent necessity to check for undefined and or null values on returns for obvious reasons (Database returns null or Request returns undefined). I didn't really worry about it before I faced myself with a huge Javascript/Nodejs project in this company, but after 6 months working on it, I find myself having to duplicate this ? very often, just like previous and current programmers on this project. My question is, is this standard behavior when programming for a reasonably big Javascript project or maybe there's another easier and/or shorter workaround this issue?

PS: Making a function that makes does checks has already been made, but it still bugs me that me and my colleagues are repeating code so often.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se]. Using exceptions with `try/except/throw` is a more manageable way to handle things.

Comment: it is not a problem by the language per se, this might happen as well in C#, java and other languages